# Warden failure application for engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, warden

I have 3 Rails 4 beta1 engines. Each engine have a different warden strategy. So my problem is now I have a global failure application. I want to every engine have own failure application. How to do it?

Sorry for poor English :)

Thank you!